# Qt GUI C++ (Android) - How to scroll outside the scroll area without touching the scroll bar?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I scroll even when not touching the scroll bar inside the scroll area? Im developing an app for android using Qt widgets Application. Thank you for your response.

Qt 5.6.0.

Comment: Use [QScroller](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscroller.html)

Comment: May I know what is the code for that?

Comment: Sure, just click "More..." at the end of the first line of the documentation I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the link becomes invalid:

The `QScroller` object is the object that stores the current position and scrolling speed and takes care of updates. `QScroller` can be triggered by a flick gesture

```
QWidget *w = ...;
QScroller::grabGesture(w, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
```

or directly like this:

```
QWidget *w = ...;
QScroller *scroller = QScroller::scroller(w);
scroller->scrollTo(QPointF(100, 100));
```

Comment: It's still not working. I still need to touch the scroll bar to move up and down. I want a feature like Flickable of Qt quick. Thank you for  your response.